# PCA in python and graphing the top 2 components against each other

Tags: python, pca

I am trying to perform PCA on a matrix (C) where each column represents a different time points and each row represents a feature and I am trying to find the top principal components and graph them against each other. I am using the mdp module and I am confused if this module returns the matrix where each row represents a principal component with most significant components in descending order.

```
import mdp
C=mdp.pca(C)
print C

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(C[2,:C.shape[1]], C[1,:C.shape[1]], 'r*')
plt.show()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [mdp docs on mdp.pca](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/api/mdp-module.html#pca):

> pca(x, **kwargs)   Filters multidimensioanl input data through its
>   principal components.
>
> **Observations of the same variable are stored on rows, different
>   variables are stored on columns.**
>
> This is a shortcut function for the corresponding node nodes.PCANode.
>   If any keyword arguments are specified, they are passed to its
>   constructor.
>
> This is equivalent to mdp.nodes.PCANode(**kwargs)(x)

To break this down, it means that you send the keyword arguments to `PCANode` to set up the constructor, then use it's `__call__` method which, according to the `PCANode` docs, actually calls its [`execute` method](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/api/mdp.nodes.PCANode-class.html#execute), which does the following:

> execute(self, x, n=None)
>
> Project the input on the first 'n' principal
>   components. If 'n' is not set, use all available components.

So you get a matrix of projections, described as above (observations of same variable on rows, different variables on columns)